# adding ngb-pagination will not load the page

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

The documentation on ngb-pagination in https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/overview causes the page to not load after adding this

```html
<ngb-pagination
  [(page)]="page"
  [pageSize]="pageSize"
  [collectionSize]="items.length"></ngb-pagination>
```

Here is my `HTML` file

```html
    <div class="body d-flex ">
        <table class="table table-hover ">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Age</th>
                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let user of users | slice: (page-1) * pageSize : page * pageSize">
                    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.age}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                    <td>action</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <ngb-pagination [(page)]="page" [pageSize]="pageSize" [collectionSize]="users.length"></ngb-pagination>
    </div>
```

Here is the `ts` file

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-table',
      templateUrl: './table.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./table.component.scss'],
    })
    export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
      readonly API_PATH = '/user/all';

      users: any[] = [];
      page = 1;
      pageSize = 5;

      constructor(private api: HttpClient) {}

      async ngOnInit() {
        this.displayAllUsers();
      }

      private async displayAllUsers() {
        var users: any = await this.getUsers();
        this.getResult(users);
      }

      private async getUsers(): Promise<any> {
        return await this.api.get(environment.API_URL + this.API_PATH).toPromise();
      }

      private getResult(result: any) {
        if (result.success) {
          this.users = this.toArray(result.data);
        } else {
          console.log(result.data);
        }
      }

      private toArray(result: any): any[] {
        var list = [];
        for (var items in result) {
          list.push(result[items]);
        }

        return list;
      }
    }
```

if I remove `ngb-pagination` snippet the page seems to load perfectly fine, but adding the snippet will fail to load the page

Comment: I'm having this same issue, after upgrading my code to ng-bootstrap 10. Prior to this upgrade it had been working.

Comment: See below. I discovered the issue when using Stackblitz to make a simplified version of my code. It showed me an error message I wasn't seeing in my angular build. Something somewhere suppresses the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the @angular/localize package to your packages.json:

```
npm install @angular/localize --save
```

Add this to your polyfills.ts:

```
import '@angular/localize/init';
```

This worked for me, when I was having the same problem after upgrading from Angular 6 to 12 and ng-bootstrap 10.

Comment: Excellent, can you click the tick for the answer accepted?

Answer (score 0):

if you get "Unrecognized token in source text." for install then use like this

```
npm install '@angular/localize' --save
```

and add below line in  polyfills.ts:

```
import '@angular/localize/init';
```